# Why does sbt assembly throw error while updating dependencies?

Tags: java, sbt

While running `sbt assembly`, it fails with the following error:

```
C:\javaeclipse>sbt assembly
...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\javaeclipse\target\resolution-cache\simple\simple_2.10\0.1.0 \resolved.xml.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
   ...   
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\javaeclipse\target\resolution-cache\simple\simple_2.10\0.1.0 \resolved.xml.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Sep 4, 2014 4:40:52 PM
```

I'm not sure what `resolved.xml.xml` is and I can't even find it in my project.

Comment: Please note the extraneous space in `version`. It *could* be the issue. Check `build.sbt` and correct `version := "0.1.0 "` to have no space.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski : The fix suggested by you worked :) . out of curiosity, how did you arrive on this solution? IMHO The solution was no way related to the error thrown .

Comment: I'm so glad. Really! I see things others can't :-) See my answer. Approve if works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the extraneous space in version as seen in the error log (after the `0.1.0` and before the following `\`):

> [error] (*:update) java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\javaeclipse\target\resolution-cache\simple\simple_2.10\0.1.0 \resolved.xml.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Fix the `version := "0.1.0 "` to have no space and start over.